# Is it free to use Spire PDF in a .NET web development and deployment to the Production server

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation

I would like to use SpirePDF in my .NET web application to load a template, fill a few fields and save it as a new pdf. I tried downloading the nuget package and its working fine as I expected. Now is the question. Is it free to use for a .NET developer in the webapp and also deploy the code in the server??

Answer (score 3):

Spire.PDF is a commercial library, so if you use it without applying a valid license, you'll see a red watermark at the top of the output files. You can request a 1-month temporary license [here](https://www.e-iceblue.com/TemLicense.html) to remove it and have a full trial on the library.

It also provides a [free community edition](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-pdf-component.html) (Free Spire.PDF) which is free for personal and commercial use, but it's limited to 10 pages when loading or saving PDF files. If it's enough for your case, go for it.